# ASP.NET modal cannot display model props

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a problem: I pass a collection to a view. Then I iterate through it and display some data. In normal markup, it works, but in modal it doesn't. Please tell me why modal code does not show the data.

Here is the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.ToDO>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @if (item.isDone == true)
    {
        <div class="done-element element">
            <p>
            Title: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
            </p>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <!-- Modal content-->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>
                            Description: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Desc)
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

EDIT: I found some strange things: all modals display this value, but all take it from the first element

EDIT2: I found the solution. Target data is ID and take first found element. Changing ID to variable fix problem.

Comment: I just tested your code and it seems to work. Maybe just recheck your model to ensure you are referencing the right property and make sure it is not empty

Comment: check out my edit. It seems to be very strange